# Optimising Eloquent Relational Queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

We are looking at optimising our Laravel Eloquent queries on our search page, we have got the number of queries executed down to a good number.

However, we do see a consistent query that is running based on a relationship. That query is :

```
select * from `property_types` where `property_types`.`id` = 7 limit 1
```

This query is running if there's a unique property type per property.

I've taken a look at has and with queries in Laravel.

The relationship is set :

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PropertyType', 'property_type_id', 'id');
}
```

We create a Property Title and URL using the relationship, so for a URL we use :

```
public function getUrlAttribute($pdf = false)
{
    $property_route = ($pdf) ? 'property-pdf' : 'property';

    // Format: /property/[NUMBER OF BEDS]-bed-[PROPERTY TYPE]-[FOR-SALE / TO-RENT]-in-[CITY]/[PROPERTY ID]
    $items = [];
    if ($this->beds) $items[] = $this->beds.' bed';
    $items[] = $this->type->name ?? 'property';
}
```

So everytime a matching property is found, It's going back over that relationship and we're seeing the property_types query running up to 15 times per page.

Is there any suggestions on optimising this?

Comment: Have you tried [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)?

Comment: just when you are making the selections add one simple ->with("RELATIONSHIP NAME") it will preload the relationships

Comment: like @acvi said you better check & use eager loading: [link here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

It will reduce the queries and will solve the N+1 problem